# adding value inside an input - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with adding value inside an input in my React component. I would like to put my generated password inside an input as a value. At the moment password is undefined.

**App.js** - main React component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    passwordValue: "start",
    rangeValue: 6
  };

  generatePassword = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var length = 8,
      charset =
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
      retPass = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
      retPass += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }

    console.log(retPass);
    this.setState({ passwordValue: retPass });
    return retPass;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Header name="lock" />
        <Generator
          submitFn={this.generatePassword}
          password={this.state.passwordValue} //props necessary for an input
        />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Generator.js** - React component used in App.js

```
const Generator = ({ submitFn, props }) => {
  return (
    <form className={styles.generatContainer}>
      //some form inputs
      <button className={styles.generatContainer__button} onClick={submitFn}>
        Generate Password
      </button>
      <div className={styles.generatContainer__input}>
        <label name="newPass">Your New Password:</label>
        <input type="text" value={props.password}></input> //here is a problem
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Generator;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not destructuring the `password` :

```
const Generator = ({ submitFn, password }) => {
  // ...
  <input type="text" value={password}></input> //here is a problem
}
```

OR :

```
const Generator = ({ submitFn, ...props }) => {
  // ...
  <input type="text" value={props.password}></input> //here is a problem
}
```